Using Daubechies-2 coefficients to find 3D DWT using pywavlets
I am currently trying to implement a 3D multi-level 3D DWT in C++ and using the 3D DWT function from pywavlets as reference.
I have noticed that after performing the 3D DWT, the pywavlets function does not split each subband into exactly one eighths which is confusing.
For example, if an image has size (78, 512, 512). Each subband should be (39, 256, 256) but the pywavlets results are (40, 257, 257). Anyone knows why ?
I tried to pad my code with zeros to maybe be able to increase the resolution but did not manage and I am not sure if this solves anything. Below is my current code (I am trying to work with Daubechies-2 coefficients) (jbutil::vector is just an aligned vector):
#include "DWT.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

jbutil::vector<float> convolve(const jbutil::vector<float>& data, bool is_low_pass) {
    size_t data_size = data.size();
    size_t N = data_size / 2;
    jbutil::vector<float> s_odd(N);
    jbutil::vector<float> s_even(N);

    // Separate odd and even samples
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        s_odd[i] = data[2 * i];
        s_even[i] = data[2 * i + 1];
    }

    jbutil::vector<float> result(N);
    float sqrt3 = std::sqrt(3);

    // Apply Daubechies-2 coefficients directly
    float a0 = (1 + sqrt3) / (4 * std::sqrt(2));
    float a1 = (3 + sqrt3) / (4 * std::sqrt(2));
    float a2 = (3 - sqrt3) / (4 * std::sqrt(2));
    float a3 = (1 - sqrt3) / (4 * std::sqrt(2));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        float sum = 0.0f;
        if (is_low_pass) {
            sum = a0 * s_odd[i] + a1 * s_even[i] 
                + a2 * s_odd[(i + 1) % N] + a3 * s_even[(i + 1) % N];
        } else {
            sum = a3 * s_odd[(i + N - 1) % N] - a2 * s_even[(i + N - 1) % N]
                + a1 * s_odd[i] - a0 * s_even[i];
        }
        result[i] = sum;
    }

    return result;
}

// Function to apply 1D convolution with odd/even separation across a specified dimension
void apply_convolution(const Custom3DArray<float>& input, Custom3DArray<float>& output_L, Custom3DArray<float>& output_H, size_t dim) {
    size_t depth = input.get_depth();
    size_t rows = input.get_rows();
    size_t cols = input.get_cols();

    if (dim == 0) { // First dimension
        for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
            for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
                jbutil::vector<float> col(depth);
                for (size_t d = 0; d < depth; ++d) {
                    col[d] = input(d, r, c);
                }
                jbutil::vector<float> L_col = convolve(col, true);  
                jbutil::vector<float> H_col = convolve(col, false); 
                for (size_t d = 0; d < static_cast<size_t>(L_col.size()); ++d) {
                    output_L(d, r, c) = L_col[d];
                    output_H(d, r, c) = H_col[d];
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (dim == 1) { // Second dimension
        for (size_t d = 0; d < depth; ++d) {
            for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
                jbutil::vector<float> row(rows);
                for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
                    row[r] = input(d, r, c);
                }
                jbutil::vector<float> L_row = convolve(row, true);  
                jbutil::vector<float> H_row = convolve(row, false); 
                for (size_t r = 0; r < static_cast<size_t>(L_row.size()); ++r) {
                    output_L(d, r, c) = L_row[r];
                    output_H(d, r, c) = H_row[r];
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (dim == 2) { // Third dimension
        for (size_t d = 0; d < depth; ++d) {
            for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
                jbutil::vector<float> col(cols);
                for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
                    col[c] = input(d, r, c);
                }
                jbutil::vector<float> L_col = convolve(col, true);  
                jbutil::vector<float> H_col = convolve(col, false); 
                for (size_t c = 0; c < static_cast<size_t>(L_col.size()); ++c) {
                    output_L(d, r, c) = L_col[c];
                    output_H(d, r, c) = H_col[c];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Function to perform multi-level 3D wavelet transform
Wavelet3DResult dwt_3d(const Custom3DArray<float>& data, int levels) {
    size_t depth = data.get_depth();
    size_t rows = data.get_rows();
    size_t cols = data.get_cols();

    // Apply 1D convolution and subsampling along the first dimension
    Custom3DArray<float> L(depth / 2, rows, cols);
    Custom3DArray<float> H(depth / 2, rows, cols);
    apply_convolution(data, L, H, 0);

    // Apply 1D convolution and subsampling along the second dimension
    Custom3DArray<float> LL(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols);
    Custom3DArray<float> LH(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols);
    Custom3DArray<float> HL(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols);
    Custom3DArray<float> HH(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols);
    apply_convolution(L, LL, LH, 1);
    apply_convolution(H, HL, HH, 1);

    // Apply 1D convolution and subsampling along the third dimension
    Custom3DArray<float> LLL(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    Custom3DArray<float> LLH(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    Custom3DArray<float> LHL(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    Custom3DArray<float> LHH(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    Custom3DArray<float> HLL(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    Custom3DArray<float> HLH(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    Custom3DArray<float> HHL(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    Custom3DArray<float> HHH(depth / 2, rows / 2, cols / 2);
    apply_convolution(LL, LLL, LLH, 2);
    apply_convolution(LH, LHL, LHH, 2);
    apply_convolution(HL, HLL, HLH, 2);
    apply_convolution(HH, HHL, HHH, 2);

    // Multi-level 
    if (levels > 1) {
        Wavelet3DResult next_level_result = dwt_3d(LLL, levels - 1);
        
        return {next_level_result.LLL, next_level_result.LLH, next_level_result.LHL, next_level_result.LHH,
                next_level_result.HLL, next_level_result.HLH, next_level_result.HHL, next_level_result.HHH};
    }

    return {LLL, LLH, LHL, LHH, HLL, HLH, HHL, HHH};
}

